# Istio not returning x-request-id HTTP header from nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, istio

I have a NGINX web server which proxies to an Istio gateway to reach a NodeJS app:

```
AWS ALB --> nginx (x3) --> AWS NLB --> (proxy) Istio gateway --> NodeJS
```

**THE PROBLEM:** When using this service Client A will occasionally (appear to) receive a response for Client B.

```
Client A sends API request
1 in 10 times Client A receives response for Client B
```

I'm trying to debug this using trace headers in Istio.

If I curl the Istio gateway directly with:

```
curl -v --request GET \
   --url "https://my-app.k8s.my-domain.com/something" \
   --header "x-envoy-force-trace: true" \
   --header "x-request-id: foobar"
```

Then I will see the `x-request-id` header in the response. However if I curl the NGINX servers with:

```
curl -v --request GET \
   --url "https://my-domain.com/something" \
   --header "x-envoy-force-trace: true" \
   --header "x-request-id: foobar"
```

The `x-request-id` header will not be returned. I added [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) in between nginx and Istio and confirmed the `x-request-id` and `x-envoy-force-trace` headers are being proxied from nginx to Istio, they just aren't returned in the response.

Can anyone advise:

- What could be causing the headers to not be returned from Istio?
- What could be causing the main problem (bold above)?

**UPDATE**: 2021-07-13

We managed to get Istio to return the `X-Forwarded-For` IP in the `x-request-id` header as follows:

```yaml
    apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
    kind: VirtualService
    metadata:
      name: vs
    spec:
      hosts:
        - my-app.my-domain.net
      http:
      - headers:
          request:
            set:
              x-envoy-force-trace: "true"
              x-request-id: "%REQ(x-forwarded-for)%"
```

From tests it looks like we don't have a mismatch issue - the problem seems to originate within the application

Comment: Perhaps adding an EnvoyFilter might help : https://www.ajohnstone.com/istio-envoyfilter-to-add-x-request-id-to-all-responses/

Comment: @PeterClaes that didn't work for me unfortunately. However adding `http.headers.request.set:` `x-envoy-force-trace: "true"` did make the `x-request-id` appear. However this alone isn't enough. Setting the `x-client-trace-id` header (so I can link a request to a response) doesn't work.